# Why is minimum width ignored?

Tags: tikz-styles

I am trying to draw a simple node with a split rectangle. `minimum height` works as expected. But `minimum width` is simply ignored. I'd like to make the node a bit wider. Below is an MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[list/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1cm}, >=stealth, start chain]
  \node[list,on chain] (A) {$A_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: At shapes `rectangle split horizontal` you can't determine parts widths, only node parts minimum height.

Comment: Ah, so there is no way of specifying the overall width of the rectangle?

Comment: No, however for empty nodes parts you can use `rectangle split empty part width=...` or  `rectangle split empty part height =...`. See description of `multipart. nodes˛. TikU & PGF manual, page 820 -- 823.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!